# Generic PHP Match Template with String

Tags: php, templates, string, match

is there a function that will allow me to do the following:

```
$template = "{name}:{city}-{state}"
$string = "Tom:Some CityPlace-CA"

$out = function_I_am_looking_for($template,$string);
```

when $out returns

```
Array(
    [name] => Tom
    [city] => Some CityPlace
    [state] => CA
)
```

Does such a function exist?

-------- EDIT -----------

So the people have spoken, and since I dont like seeing something like this die, I will conclude.  No built in function exists, however I did mock up one, and it does work.  Feel free to refine, please comment you edits.

```
function genaric_match($template,$string,$varStart="{{",$varEnd="}}"){


  $template = str_replace($varStart,"|~|`",$template);
  $template = str_replace($varEnd,"`|~|",$template);

  $t=explode("|~|",$template);

  $temp="";
  $i=0;
  foreach ($t as $n=>$v){
    $i++;
    if (($i==count($t)||($i==(count($t)-1)&&$t[$n+1]==""))&&substr($v,0,1)=="`"&&substr($v,-1)=="`"){
      //Last Item
      $temp.="(?P<".substr($v,1,-1).">.++)";

    }elseif(substr($v,0,1)=="`"&&substr($v,-1)=="`"){
      //Search Item
      $temp.="(?P<".substr($v,1,-1).">[^".$t[$n+1]."]++)";

    }else{
      $temp.=$v;
    }

  }
  $temp="~^".$temp."$~";

  preg_match($temp, $string, $matches);

  return $matches;

}
```

This example

```
print_r(genaric_match("{{name}}:{{city}}-{{state}}","Tom:Some CityPlace-CA"));
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tom:Some CityPlace-CA
    [name] => Tom
    [1] => Tom
    [city] => Some CityPlace
    [2] => Some CityPlace
    [state] => CA
    [3] => CA
)
```

Comment: Seems to me like you've never been introduced to regular expressions. There's already a well formed, well accepted and mature syntax for pattern matching. Read up on regular expressions for more info.

Comment: I have, however I am trying to write a piece of code that takes advantage of the simpler way of "string templating"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match). But you obviously need to write a regex for it. (If your question is, whether there is a magic recognize-any-pattern-without-even-knowing-it's-syntax function, then the answer is: No.)

```
preg_match('~^(?P<name>[^:]++):(?P<city>[^-]++)-(?P<state>.++)$~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Right answer but might be slightly cleaner to use `preg_split` instead of `preg_match` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). EDIT: actually `preg_match` is better in this case.

Comment: @Nitroware: Good luck with that ;) It'll be pretty hard to create a function, which generates efficient (!) PCREs from simple templates. Generating slow regexes is no problem, but keeping them fast, that'll be hard ;)

Comment: Couldn't I so like a str_replace("{","(?P<",$template) or something?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function in PHP "out of the box", but it would be fairly trivial to write one, as there are quite a few functions such as...

- [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [parse_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
- etc.

...that you could use to create one.

However, it has to be said that using PHP (which is to a large extent a template language) to create *another* template language seems an odd choice.